# Fill Holes wont work

Tags: mesh

I need to fill these holes in the mesh.
The fill holes command doesnt work - There are no double vertices.I have also tried to use decimate modifier bevore.Also i cannot use edge loop to fill it manually.

Please help out - thanks
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the error displayed?

Comment: hi and thanks. No error message as far as i can see - nothing happen. i attached a new screen showing info box.

Comment: Are you selecting the entire mesh this way? Because Blender will not recognize the upper right "hole" as a hole, since its not closed, nothing will happen. Additionally your sides modifier might not be enough.

Comment: ok thanks - i deleted the mentioned hole - but doesnt work. Can it fill out only one hole ?

Comment: Have you increased the amount of sides as I suggested? For these irregular shapes it will need to be quite high. Like above 50 i would think.

Comment: yes i just tried it out with 50 - but no sucess :/

Comment: Then the holes are simply too complex to fill. But try the slider to maximum.